# Unity3D: Create scripts to climb a ladder

Tags: unity-game-engine, eventtrigger, rigid-bodies

I'm inexperienced and I'm trying to understand the mechanism for using a ladder with my character or climbing over small walls. To move I use a rigidbody not kinematic, but with `AddForce`. I tried to create an object to simulate a ladder to climb on. To get my character into contact with the ladder I inserted a collider trigger on the ladder and called the `OnTriggerStay` function. After working a bit, my character now with a bool when he's close enough, he can go up or down the ladder but I don't understand some things. First of all, the script is better to put it on the character or create one on the scale? The second thing is once you get to the top how to insert a function correctly and make my character complete the climb, making it arrive above the object where the staircase is located. Do I have to get to the top, destroy the game object and respawn at a point just above the ladder? ... what is the best way in these cases?

```
        private Rigidbody rb;
    public bool ladderClimb = false;
    void Start()
        {
         rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
        }

     void Update()
        {
         if(ladderClimb){
    directionRot = new Vector3(0, 0, 0);  //direction of rotation
    movement = new Vector3(0, Input.GetAxisRaw("Vertical"), 0).normalized; //object movement
      rb.useGravity = false;}
       else rb.useGravity = true;
    }

        void OnTriggerStay(Collider collider){
         if(collider.gameObject.tag == "ladder"){
         if(Input.GetKeyUp(KeyCode.E)) ladderClimb = !ladderClimb;}}

    void OnTriggerExit(Collider collider){
       if(collider.gameObject.tag == "ladder") ladderClimb = false;}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a trigger collider to the ladder and check if the player is touched to the collider then disable gravity and allow vertical movement. But in case the object detaches from the ladder the reenable the gravity  and restrict the vertical movement.

Comment: Sorry but, that's what I've already done in my code. What I want to know is, once at the top of the ladder, how do I finish the climb?
The player is in third person so at the end I need a script that links the exit from the ladder with the arrival of the player above the wall where the ladder is located

Comment: If that is the case then add a empty gameobject at the top of every ladder and check if the distance between the player and ladder top is less than specified distance, then add a small amount of force to move it to the top and enable the solid box collider. The solid box collider must touch the surface of the wall. So that when player again touches the solid box collider and presses down arrow key then disable the gravity, solid collider and reenable the vertical movement.

Comment: Remember to add a solid box collider i.e. a box collider that has no trigger functionality which just touch the wall so that you can determine when player has stepped on the ladders top again.